# Issues searching backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I have this bb app that I'm trying to search and return the results of the search, then when cleared, so all results again. I was able to get everything to show before adding the search feature, but now nothing showing up. I think the collection isn't available at the time it's trying to populate, but can't seem to get it to wait. I've tried moving the fetch around to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciate. For the sake of ease, I've put everything in a fiddle that can be found here...

```
//Campaign Model w defaults
app.model.Campaign = Backbone.Model.extend({
    default: {
        title: '',
        img: '',
        id: '',
        slug: '',
        image_types: 'small',
        tagline: ''
    }
});


//Campaign Collection from model
app.collection.Campaign = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    //our URL we're fetching from
    url: 'https://api.indiegogo.com/1/campaigns.json?api_token=e377270bf1e9121da34cb6dff0e8af52a03296766a8e955c19f62f593651b346',
    parse: function(response) { 
        console.log('parsing...');
        return response.response; //get array from obj to add to collection based on model
    },
    currentStatus: function(status){
        return _(this.filter(function(data){
            console.log('currentStats', status);
            return data.get('_pending') == status;
        }));
    },
    search: function(searchVal) {
        console.log('search...');
        if (searchVal == '') {
            return this;
        }

        var pattern = new RegExp(searchVal, 'gi');
        return _(this.filter(function(data) { 
            return pattern.test(data.get('title'));
        }));
    }
});

app.collection.campaigns = new app.collection.Campaign();
app.collection.campaigns.fetch({
    success: function(){ 
        console.log('Success...');

        var sHeight = window.screen.availHeight - 200 + 'px';
        $('#container ul').css('height', sHeight);
    },
    error: function() { 
        console.log('error ',arguments);
    }
});


//List view for all the campaigns
app.view.CampaignList = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    events: {
        'keyup #searchBox': 'search'
    },
    render: function(data) { 
        console.log('campaignList',$(this.el).html(this.template));
        $(this.el).html(this.template);
        return this;
    },
    renderAll: function(campaigns) { 
        console.log('campList renderAll', campaigns, $('#campaignList'));
        $('#campaignList').html('');
        campaigns.each(function(campaign){ 
            var view = new app.view.CampaignItem({
                model: campaign,
                collection: this.collection
            });
            console.log(view);
            $('#campaignList').append(view.render().el);
        });
        return this;
    },
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('init campList',app);
        this.template = _.template($('#campaignList-tmp').html());
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
    },
    search: function(e) {
        console.log('listView search');
        var searchVal = $('#searchBox').val();
        this.renderAll(this.collection.search(searchVal));
    },
    sorts: function() {
        var status = $('#campSorting').find('option:selected').val();
        if(status == '') {
            status = false;
        };
        this.renderAll(this.collection.currentStatus(status));
    }
});

//Item view for single campaign
app.view.CampaignItem = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {},
    render: function(data){
        console.log('campItem render...', data);
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('campItem init');
        this.template = _.template( $('#campaignItem-tmp').html());
    }
});

//Router
app.router.Campaign = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'campaigns'
    },
    campaigns: function(){
        this.campListView = new app.view.CampaignList({
            collection: app.collection.campaigns
        });
        $('#container').append(this.campListView.render().el);
        this.campListView.sorts();
    }
});

app.router.campaigns = new app.router.Campaign();
Backbone.history.start();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skipzero/xqvrpyx8/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xqvrpyx8/8/

Comment: thanks. I'll compare that to what I have and see where I went wrong, or you're welcome to point it out. :)
I appreciate the help.